# Storing WP Variable from cart meta (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some issues trying to retrieve and store a variable from the cart meta - The loop is working fine using the code below:

```
if (WC()->cart) {

         foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {
           $product = $item['data'];
           $prod_id = wdcp_get_product_id_cart_item($item);
           echo $product;
         }
    }
```

Result:

```
{"id":26036,"key":"_credits_amount","value":"15"}
```

I would like to take this value (_credits_amount) and store it in a variable but cant figure out how to pinpont locate it via the code... any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode JSON:

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {
    $product = $item['data'];
    $prod_id = wdcp_get_product_id_cart_item($item);
    $data = json_decode( $product, true);
    echo $data['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this data are **object of type WC_Product_Simple**  so id you want to get the `_credits_amount` and store it in variable you can do so as follow:

```
$key = $product->key;
```

**full code :**

```
if (WC()->cart) {

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {

    $product = $item['data'];
    $key = $product->key;

    echo $key;

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks kashalo, but that doesnt seem to work. it is not a simple type product as it is woo credits - i was thinking something along the lines of:
`$credit_number = wdcp_get_product_id_cart_item($item, '_credit_amount', true);`

Comment: @thefonz am not sure what this function is but i believe it's not part of Woocommerce